# SQL: find the closest float values

Tags: mysql, sql

MariaDB/MySQL ***without window function support***.

```
Table DEVICE {
 id int,   <— Primary key
 name  varchar(10)  
}
```

For every device there are many records in DATA table

```
Table DATA (
  device_id   int,    <— Foreign key to DEVICE.id
  value float
)
```

User provides some target_value.

Task: find the closest values in DATA table for every device.

```
DEVICE
-----------
id |  name 
-----------
1  |  A
2  |  B
3  |  C


       DATA
------------------------
device_id      |  value 
------------------------
 1             |  5.3
 1             |  5.9
 2             |  4.0
 2             |  4.5
 3             |  5.1
```

For the input target_value=5.0 the expected output is:

```
--------------------
id |  value 
---------------------
 1 |  5.3
 2 |  4.5
 3 |  5.1
```

I know how to find closest value for a single device (e.g. device_id=2):

```
SELECT device_id, value FROM DATA 
WHERE device_id=2 ORDER BY ABS(value-target_value) ASC LIMIT 1
```

... but I do not know how to extend it to return results for several device_id's

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SELECT
  d.device_id, d.`value`
FROM
  `DATA` d
JOIN
  device dev on dev.id = d.device_id
WHERE
  ROUND(ABS(d.`value`-5.0)) = 0
ORDER BY d.device_id;

Comment: This answer is wrong. More specifically,  this part  is not correct: 
    ROUND(ABS(d.value-5.0)) = 0  because d.value is not guaranteed  to be  in range 4.0-6.0